# Send email via Thunderbird (Enigmail) as HTML

Tags: email, thunderbird, pgp, enigmail

I'm having a problem that I want to use Thunderbird in combination with the Enigmail addodn to send and recieve emails that are enrypted by PGP. I can already view emails that are sent to me as HTML, however, when trying to write an email, the formatting is lost.

I stumbled upon [HTML or rich e-mails do not work with Enigmal in Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/282016/html-or-rich-e-mails-do-not-work-with-enigmal-in-thunderbird), but "Always use PGP/MIME" is already checked in my account settings and I'm sending both HTML and plain text as an email. I just want to use HTML in my signature. This is needed. How can I achieve that?

In AppleMail it works without any problems. However, I want to use either Postbox or Thunderbird.

**UPDATE**

I still can't fix this problem. I even used Postbox, which is based on Thunderbird, and I'm having the same problem there. Any ideas?